# adding button in android listview

Tags: android, listview, button

Hi in my application i am taking listview and i add some data coming from json in that at the end i added one button if i click the button i want to move to another activity but if i click the add button my application got crashed.can any one please help me Thanks in advance.

ImageAdapterNew.java:

```
  public class ImageAdapterNew extends Activity {

        ListView mListView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   


            // URL to the JSON data         
            String strUrl = "http://indianpoliticalleadersmap.com/android/DemoSchool/json/json_item.php";

            // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data 
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Starting the download process
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

            // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
                    //String content = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                    //Button place = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2));
                    //String datetime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datetime)).getText().toString();
                    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
                            startActivity(in);  
                        }
                    });



                    /*in.putExtra(TAG_PLACE, place);
                    *///in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, content);
                    //in.putExtra(TAG_DATETIME, datetime);


                }
            });



        }

        /** A method to download json data from url */
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            try{
                    URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Connecting to url 
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Reading data from url 
                    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                    StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                    String line = "";
                    while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    data = sb.toString();

                    br.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            }finally{
                    iStream.close();
            }

            return data;
        }



        /** AsyncTask to download json data */
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
            String data = null;
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                            try{
                                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                            }
                            return data;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                            // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
                            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

                            // Start parsing xml data
                            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);                        

                    }
        }

        /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
        private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

            JSONObject jObject;
            // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
            @Override
            protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
                try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                    Schedule1 countryJsonParser = new Schedule1();
                    countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
                }

                // Instantiating json parser class
                Schedule1 countryJsonParser = new Schedule1();

                // A list object to store the parsed countries list
                List<HashMap<String, Object>> schedule = null;

                try{
                    // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                    schedule = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                }          

                // Keys used in Hashmap 
                String[] from = { "itemname","image"};

                // Ids of views in listview_layout
                int[] to = { R.id.tv_country,R.id.iv_flag};

                // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
                // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), schedule, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);  

                return adapter;
            }

            /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

                // Setting adapter for the listview
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                    HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                    String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                    ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                    HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                    hm.put("position", i);

                    // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
                    imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
                }
            }       
        }

        /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
        private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

            @Override
            protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

                InputStream iStream=null;
                String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
                int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

                URL url;
                try {
                    url = new URL(imgUrl);

                    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Connecting to url                
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Reading data from url 
                    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    // Getting Caching directory 
                    File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                    // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
                    File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/india_"+position+".png");              

                    // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                    // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              

                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.flush();

                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                    fOutStream.close();             

                    // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                    HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                    hmBitmap.put("image",tmpFile.getPath());

                    // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                    hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

                    // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                    return hmBitmap;                


                }catch (Exception e) {              
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

logcat:

```
06-14 16:33:24.274: W/dalvikvm(1592): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method myClickHandler(View) in the activity class com.example.hotel.ImageAdapterNew for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'add'
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2059)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myClickHandler
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:985)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2052)
06-14 16:33:24.285: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: hi can you please tell me

Comment: i think you implement custom adapter and try to handle onClick() in getView().

Comment: can you give some example how to create

Comment: but i want to get the data from json

Comment: by using custom adapter its possibile

Comment: can you please give me some reference or link or example

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
```

put this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(ImageAdapterNew.this, First.class);
```

Comment: can you post your logcat error... and the code where error occured

Comment: hi can you please tell me

Comment: can you tell me how to write that one

Answer (score 0):

Why you have put this click listener inside the onItemClickListener, you need to write this outside of it.

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
                    //String content = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                    //Button place = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2));
                    //String datetime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datetime)).getText().toString();
                    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent in = new Intent(ImageAdapterNew.this, First.class);
                            startActivity(in);  
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: my application crashed

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
   
    
    
    
    /*in.putExtra(TAG_PLACE, place);
    *///in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, content);
    //in.putExtra(TAG_DATETIME, datetime);
    

   }
  });

Comment: Actually this button is outside the listview or inside each and every row, this button is???

Comment: inside this what i need to add

Comment: only one button only i used in xml

Comment: Then dont implement onItemClick event, and only implement button onClick event, because if you implement both then your listview will not find which click event it is, so by default it will take ListView Click Event

Comment: But that button is in every row or outside the listview?

Comment: inside listview only i added the button

Comment: can you tell me where i did mistake

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding button in every row of list then you have to put click lisetener of the button in your getView method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi=convertView;
    if(vi==null)
        vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.catgridres,null);
        Button button=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.layout_inflator.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do your code here.
        }

    });
    return vi;
}
For your task I think Custom Adapter is more efficient.
```

Comment: where i need to add this code because in my code there is no getview method

Comment: i also suggest you create a custom adapter class for the listview which have the Button. when you get the id of the button in getview place your click listener there.

Answer (score 0):

First You should put your errors from logcat that can help to get exact problem on your code

Second I think your button is from different layout so you have to finviewbyid from view.

```
Button button=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.layout_inflator.button1);
```

Comment: in layout only o added

Comment: can you please tell me what i did mistake